# Toggle Button work only 1st time android

Tags: android, performance

I'have writing code of save Toggle Button State. But it Work only 1st time. 2nd time its Not work. when I restart my Toggle button after close it.

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    edit = prefs.edit();

    tb = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);   
    tb.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean("main_state", false));       
    tb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

     // Toggle Button Save States ------------------------------------------
    tb.setOnClickListener(new ToggleButton.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("main_state", tb.isChecked());
            editor.commit();
        }
    });
```

### On chackedChange

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
    if (arg1) {
        edit.putBoolean("main_state", arg1);            

    } else {
        edit.putBoolean("main_state", arg1);

    }
    edit.commit();
}
```

so what is problem?

Comment: what do you use this if-clause for in your `onCheckedChanged`???

Comment: remove tb.setOnCLickListener and try, it will work and save the toggle button state in onCheckedChangeListner

Comment: i'have start service on if-clause. @ZerO

Comment: how can i do this..?? @Madhu

Comment: @user3855491 no you do the same thing in `if` and `else`

Comment: ohk.. so wht i have to do???

Comment: problem solve brother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    ToggleButton tb;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tb=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.app_name), MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        tb.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("main_state",false));
        tb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                editor.putBoolean("main_state",isChecked);
                editor.commit();
            }
        });
    }

}
```